# Кросс-компиляция из Windows под Linux. Получение бинарных файлов под Linux

Tags: windows, c, c++, linux

Мне поставили задачу - разобраться с кросскомпиляцией C и C++ приложений из под Windows для Linux.

Я попробовал использовать Cygwin для этих целей. Установил эту оболочку, запустил её. Установил компилятор cygwin-gcc-3.3.6-glibc-2.3.2-linux (старый правда). И попробовал из него скомпилировать обычный HelloWorld и запустить его под Linux всё получилось.

Но задача стоит чтобы из нашего Windows-приложения запускать кросс-компилятор, который будет компилировать некоторые файлы. Как вообще это можно реализовать? Просто в данном случае приходится запускать Cygwin, а уже из него gcc-linux или  g++-linux. Пока не вижу путей запуска из нашего приложения Windows Cygwin и далее уже в нём запуска компилятора.

Может быть какие-то есть другие выходы из ситуации? Как-то можно настроить вообще отдельный компилятор по Windows, который будет компилить бинарники под Linux?

Comment: Может это поможет - http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinGW


Comment: Ну это я читал и он у меня установлен. Я пока не могу найти в интернете про то как реально компилить на нём

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Установить cygwin.
2. Создать скрипт запускающий сборку.
3. Вызвать скрипт из приложения.

В скрипте (cmd-файл)

```
set CYGWIN_BIN=c:\cygwin\bin

CYGWIN_BIN\gcc.exe ...
```

В приложении

```
CreateProcess(...)
```

А еще есть такое средство для кросс-компиляций: [crosstool-ng](http://crosstool-ng.org/#features).

Comment: хм, спасибо большое за хороший ответ! Первый вариант буду прорабатывать, спасибо за наводки :) crosstool-ng попозже посмотрю

Comment: нужный мне компилятор я под Gywin собрал. А вы не можете поподробнее подсказать, как запустить мне Cygwin из моего windows приложения, а потом как бы прописать автоматически в bash Cywin что нужно скомпилить

Comment: а еще лучше так:  
SET CYGWIN_HOME=C:\cygwin  
PATH = %CYGWIN_HOME%\bin;%PATH%;  
echo a b c d | grep -v a

Answer (score 3):

А разве gcc.exe из cygwin не нужны cygwin-овские .dll ? По моему их загружает bash при старте окошка cygwn.

По крайней мере у меня (Windows-XP) влет не получилось. c:\cygwin\bin\gcc t.c  из cmd потребовал cygwin1.dll

Вам надо разобраться с инициализацией cygwin, с загрузкой dll.

А вот так получилось:

c:\cygwin\bin\bash -c "gcc t.c"

Только **абсолютно не уверен**, что полученный модуль будет работать в Linux.

Comment: полученный модуль не будет работать под линукс. Только если не запускать его под wine. Для запуска под линуксом нужна перекомпиляция - т.е. чтобы формат исполняемоего файла был a.out или ELF и были прилинкованы линуксовые библиотеки.

Касательно cygwin1.dll - справедливо. Но зависимости от библиотек легко посмотреть с помощью Dependency Viewer. И если положить рядом с программой все необходимые ей библиотеки, то она будет работать в любой винде =) даже на той, на которой не стоит Cygwin

Comment: смысл в том, что нужен кросс компилятор, я брал вот отсюда: http://kegel.com/crosstool/

т.е. собрал нужный мне компилятора, скомпилировал им под Cygwin и получил бинарник, который НЕ ЗАПУСКАЕТСЯ под Cygwin и нормально работает под Linux без доп. библиотек

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то можно использовать pipe'ы чтобы скармливать через них команды в cygwin для g++-linux.