# Тип проекта

Tags: eclipse, c++, linux

Какой шаблон c++ проекта надо выбирать для компиляции на linux в eclipse и не нужно ли для этого иметь gcc на Windows?

Answer (score 1):

Если вам нужно скомпилировать проект из-под Windows, то нужно выбрать либо Cross GCC, либо MinGW в качестве компилятора для вашего проекта, тип шаблона зависит от того, что вы собираетесь компилировать(приложение, подключаемую библиотеку и т.д.). Перед этим, естественно, нужно поставить выше упомянутые программы.

[Еще про кросс-компиляцию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/33165/%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%B7-windows-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4-linux-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4-linux)